# What are you going now ? (Is it right question)

Tags: questions

I think it have no meaning, please confirm 
This question is at my daughter homework sheet and i have no answer to it because I didn’t get what they wanted to know

Comment: First what do you have in mind to say by that? And I think you should say 'where are you going?' or at least 'What place are you going to?'

Comment: This question is at my daughter homework sheet and i have no answer to it because I didn’t get what they wanted to know

Comment: It might have been a typo. I don't think I've ever heard such a question.

Comment: It might have been "what are you **doing** now", perhaps.

Comment: Or "What are you going *to do* now?"

Answer (score 1):

> What are you going now?

...does not make sense. Homework and other published sources of "correct English" can often have typos. Possible correct sentences include:

> **Where** are you **going** now?
>
> **What** are you **doing** now?

Without more context, there is no way to know what the original intention was.